# Excel, Chinese mojibake error

Tags: ms-office, encoding

On Mac, the Excel show mojibake 
[image]

However with Numbers it can show the right content. How can I set Excel to show Chinese characters?

My system language is English.

Answer (score 1):

From [this other question](https://superuser.com/questions/280603/how-to-set-character-encoding-when-opening-excel) regarding excel encoding:

[image]